# After wiping the ios device, I cannot enroll to the CISCO SCEP server

Tags: ios, mdm

My iOS 4/5 devices have been enrolling with the CISCO SCEP server all along.

However, after I OTA wiped the device, it no longer enrolls.

Maybe someone can help me here - somehow I suspect it's the problem with the certificate, that after wiping,  something's changed on the device.

Need suggestions on how to debug this issue.

I am tempted to jail broke the device to see the certificate changes, if any, after the wipe.

I have already resorted wireshark, tcpdump, etc to capture the payload.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking at logging on the SCEP server first of all. Perhaps it believes these devices already have a certificate allocated and are blocking enrolment. SCEP was original designed to issue "hardware" certs. So perhaps it thinks your devices should already have these certs. Maybe look into revoking the previous certs, or at least look at the issued/revoked certs to see if there is an answer in there.

Can you gather console logs from IPCU for us to see.

Also check that your certificate hosting the SCEP service is still valid. I believe the handshake can fail here too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Cisco router is not able to parse the HTTPS POST sent by the iPhone during profile exchanges.

The newer iPhone's factory built-in certificate (used in all HTTPS requests) encoded the SubjectName is IA5String, while the Cisco router is conformant to the RFC 2945 and can only parse Subject name encoded in PrintableString.

There is nothing much you can do about Cisco router, as using Cisco router just for SCEP/device enrollment OTA is not a natural fit.

Apple, of course, is not going to change how the cert is formed.

Your best bet to solve this problem is to

1. write your own proxy to handle the HTTPS POST, and
2. find a SCEP alternatives

The SCEP part is independent of the HTTPS POST imposed by the MDM profile configuration.  You can have the iPhone to talk to your SCEP server directly.

Essentially, Cisco router lumped the profile setup with the SCEP.

I finally got my working.  Hope this experience helps others.